# Dynamic field in a Django model

Tags: django, dynamic

I have a Django model that have some fields as following.

I would like to get advice regarding the pros and cons of adding dynamically some attributes to those models (based on some calculations that depend on real-time information from the user session).

I'm happy with the current implementation, but I'm somehow concerned about the implications in the long-term.
Is it considered a bad Design Pattern? In this case are there alternatives that permit to do that more cleanly? 
Is it cleaner to make the calculations in template tags?

Maybe putting this logic in a manager? Proxy model?
I thought doing this as properties, but the calculations depend on the request object, so it has to be done in the view somehow.

Thanks a lot.

```
class Printer(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User)

    minimal_cost = models.IntegerField()

    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)



def some_view(request):
       for printer in printer_list:
            printer.distance = printer.distance_point(user_point)
            printer.materials_costs = MaterialsCosts(printer, cart=cart)
            printer.minimum_price = printer.materials_costs.minimum_printer_price()
```

Comment: What restricts you from doing those calculations at database level using Django's aggregation or something similar?

Comment: Those are non-trivial calculations.
For instance distance calculation is not supported out of the box by Django (only GeoDjango).

Are you implying that this dynamic fields are bad style?

Comment: Questions regarding optimizing of existing code (especially code that is working without errors) are best suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

You can move your calculation method to models.py, you should not perform such calculations inside a view directly.

```
class Printer(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User)

    minimal_cost = models.IntegerField()

    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

   @classmethod
   def set_my_attrs(cls):
        printer_list = cls.objects.all() #Im assuming that you need all the printers for your calculations
        for printer in printer_list:
            printer.distance = printer.distance_point(user_point)
            printer.materials_costs = MaterialsCosts(printer, cart=cart)
            printer.minimum_price = printer.materials_costs.minimum_printer_price()
            printer.save() # dont forget saving :)
```

Then in your views.py

```
def some_view(request):

      Printer.set_my_attrs()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
The calculations I make do not mean to be persistent.
They are valid only for one calculation and that's it, I dont wan't to save them to the DB.

Still is it better to set them in the model?

Comment: @cyberjoac in that case, you should create something like services.py and move your calculations over there. I always have 3 layers, views.py to handle request and responses. services.py  implement complex calculations and other stuff that is not related directly with my model and finally my models.py, over there I put all methods that modifies my Model instances.